# Adding tasks from backlog to sprint

Tags: jira, sprint

I'm new to Jira. Today I created a sprint and was adding tasks from a backlog to the sprint. The backlog contained a hundred of tasks assigned to a team members. I was going through the backlog and figuring out who is assignee (because in the backlog only the first letter of an assignee is shown) and whether we planned this task for this sprint or for the next one. Then I right-clicked it sent it to the sprint. It was very tedious! I don't think it is the supposed way to add tasks to a sprint.

Could you please tell me what is the right way?

I would prefer to find all tasks assigned to a team member at first and then send some of them to a sprint, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your backlog should be sorted by priority. If this is the case you can just pull the bottom of the sprint down to include the tickets you want. There is a little grabber just above the horizontal rule above the backlog. Besides this right-click adding is the way to go. You can select multiple tasks before right-click adding.

By only seeing the first letter of the assignee I assume you're talking about the default avatar picture. I would recommend your team updates these to something people can identify. You can also configure your Card Layout to show the assignee in the board configuration.

Since you're considering assignees when planning I suggest configuring your board to add Quick Filters board so you can only show tickets assigned to a specific employee. I would create one for each employee, this can be handy in other meetings too. e.g. JQL: assignee=embedc